# Using an std::function for wrapping a function object

Tags: c++, c++14, std-function, function-object

Can someone help me to understand why the following code causes an error?

```
class A
{
  public:
    float& operator()()
    {
     return _f;
    }

  private:
    float _f = 1;
} a;


auto& foo()
{
  std::function<float()> func = a;
  return func();
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << foo() << std::endl;
}
```

Error:

```
error: non-const lvalue reference to type 'float' cannot bind to a temporary of type 'float'
  return func();
         ^~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Here, in `operator()`, I return a reference to `_f`and consequently, I thought `func()` is not a temporary.
It would be great if someone helps me understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `std::function<float()> func`, you're declaring `func` as a functor returning a `float`, not a `float&`. As the error message said, the temporary `float` returned by `func()` can't be bound to non-const lvalue reference.

The above declaration doesn't match the signature of `A::operator()` which being wrapped. But note that if change the type to `std::function<float&()> func` to match the signature of `A::operator()`, the compile error could be sovled, but then we'll return a reference bound to local variable, which leads to UB.

Note that for `std::function<float()> func = a;`, [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/function) is initialized with a copy of `a`. Then `func()` will return a reference bound to member of `A` wrapped in `func`, which is a local variable. And the reference will dangle when get out of function `foo`.

How to fix it depends on your design, change `auto& foo()` to `auto foo()`, i.e. passing the return value by copy would avoid UB here.

Comment: I thought so too, because it then compiles fine, but I'm afraid it's UB, because it does not seem to run correctly (e.g. it crashes or prints 0).

Comment: I found this question interesting: if you make it `auto&` and `<float&()>`, it can work; if you make it `auto` and `<float()>` it also works. Which one is correct? I feel that the `auto` and `<float()>` one is correct since you shouldn't return local variable by reference, right?

Comment: @MarsonMao Yes, we shouldn't return reference bound to local, the point is `foo` should return by copy here. (It's still unknown why OP needs return by reference.)

Answer (score 5):

The problem isn't the use of `std::function`, its that you're trying to return the temporary `float` from `func()` as a reference.
This won't work since the object would cease to exist as soon as the statement ends.

If you change `auto& foo()` to `auto foo()` it should work.

Comment: If you leave the `<float()>` unchanged, why it can compile? Isn't `A`'s operator returning `float&`?

Comment: Because it can copy-construct a new `float` from a `float&`.

Answer (score 3):

I think you understand that returning a reference to a local variable isn't valid once the variable goes out of scope. What you seem to be missing though is that `std::function<float()> func = a;` actually creates a local `std::function` from `a`. It doesn't point to `a` in any way, `func` has it's own `A`. Which means that calling `func();` doesn't actually invoke `a.operator()` but rather the `A` of `func`. Then we get back to the local variable returning a reference is evil part.

To make it compile, you can change your template signature to `float&()` but it's still undefined behaviour.

A fix would be to change the return type to a copy instead (to `auto`), removing the reference.

Comment: Why `std::function<float()> func = a;` causes no problem? Isn't `A`'s operator signature `float&`? Is it because they are compatible?

Comment: @MarsonMao It does cause a problem, a compilation problem that can be fixed by changing to `float&()`. However, this still causes UB. Which is why we can't return by reference.

Comment: I can compile and execute it fine with `auto foo()` and `std::function<float()> func = a;`. I found this interesting. Could you please explain why? (I'm using  VS2015)

Comment: @MarsonMao Because it makes a copy of the reference returned in that case. Good eye though.

Comment: I did some test and found that when you are returning `auto foo()`, you can have both `<float()> f = a;` and `<float&()> = a;` working. This is kind of weird since it should only allow `<float&()> = a;` isn't it? I mean because the signature is `float& operator()()`, so why does `<float()>` also work?

Answer (score 1):

After reading the great answers above, I tried to give some different thoughts.

I guess OP really wants to return a `float&` of a certain object (which is `a` in OP's example).

So if OP wants `foo` to return `auto&` (which should be a `float&`), then it should be as the following, please note the `std::bind` part:

```
namespace T1
{
class A
{
public:
    float& operator()()
    {
        std::cout << "a add = " << this << std::endl;
        return _f;
    }

    float getF() { return _f; }

private:
    float _f = 1;
} a;

auto& foo()
{
    std::function<float&()> func = std::bind(&A::operator(), &a);
    return func();
}
} // end of namespace T1

int main()
{
    std::cout << "global a add = " << &(T1::a) << std::endl; // check a's address
    float& f = T1::foo(); // note that `a`'s address is the same
    std::cout << f << std::endl; // still 1
    f = 777;
    std::cout << f << std::endl; // now 777
    std::cout << T1::a.getF() << std::endl; // it's 777

    return 0;
}
```